# How do you present an API where the underlying method uses an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this class called `Tasks`.

```
public class Tasks
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Status { get; set; }
}

public enum TaskStatuses
{
  NotComplete,
  Complete
}
```

The method public to clients in the business class looks like this:

```
public void StatusUpdate(TaskStatuses status, int taskId)
{
  //stuff
}
```

`TaskStatuses` is an `enum` and represents if the task is completed or not. If I design a Web API endpoint around that method, what would that look like for the client?

Will I present the resource as an int and in comments somewhere explaining that if you pass 0 it means not complete and 1 means complete?

Comment: Why don't you add a controller using that enum and check the result? Aren't you using Swashbuckle or simmilar to create Swagger documentation?

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: I know it doesn't cover other scenarios where this may arise, but in this particular case you could simply make that a boolean instead of using the enum...ie your variable can be public bool IsComplete

Comment: So, how are you creating the API documentation?

Comment: I don't have an API yet, still working on it

Comment: This entirely depends on your serialization choice(s), your desired rpc type (rest, odata, soap, etc), and how you want api consumers to behave.

Comment: Well, don't leave this for the last moment, add Swashbucle integration from the beginning, that will allow you to see and test the API without any client. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Swagger-integration-in-da408b29

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this Action in your Api

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Api/Values/StatusUpdate")]
 public void StatusUpdate(TaskStatuses status, int taskId)
 {
            //stuff
 }
```

And this Enum

```
public enum TaskStatuses
{
  NotComplete,
  Complete
}
```

When you call this Action this way

```
PUT
http://localhost:58330/Api/Values/StatusUpdate?status=1&taskId=12
```

**Yes** it means **Complete** and **0 is NotComplete**

But you can also have this call

```
PUT
http://localhost:58330/Api/Values/StatusUpdate?status=115&taskId=12
```

In this case you don't have an equivalent to 115 in your Enum, however it is also allowed and you have to handle this in your code.

Comment: You can also use `http://localhost:58330/Api/Values/StatusUpdate?status=NotComplete&taskId=12` depending on the serialization settings.